# Nuget package failing on Install and on push

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I recently created a huge NuGet package (more than 2000 files, most of them just Content, and 15Mb). Creating a NuSpec and packing it worked fine.

Then I went to a next step: testing it.

First I tried intalling it locally, but the installation failed after installing all dependencies and couldn't install the package itself. Rollback happened.

Then I uploaded to the local server, just to be sure the problem wasn't Visual Studio trying to find the package, and it failed. I searched on how to get more details on the error and used this command line:

`nuget push MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg -Source "http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package" "API-KEY" -Verbosity detailed -ForceEnglishOutput`

The return is as follows:

```
Pushing MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg to 'http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package'...
  PUT http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/ 645ms
  PUT http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/ 315ms
  PUT http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError http://localhost/myserver/api/v2/package/ 277ms
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<>c.<PushPackageToServer>b__21_3(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<ProcessResponseAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<PushPackageToServer>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<PushPackageCore>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<PushPackage>d__14.MoveNext()
```

Could you help me figure it out what the problem is? Sadly I can't post the package for privacy issues (I'm developing for the company I work in).

Answer (score 1):

Have encountered a similar error and again it was the same 500 
and the error message was not helpful.

```
2019-08-20T09:29:15.4059254Z System.AggregateException: 
One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

In this case the culprit was the Outopus Deploy server, 
which was running out of **disk space**.

Freed up disk space from deleting the old packages and was able to resolve it smoothly.

Alternatively you may increase the volume size (if it is a cloud storage like AWS EBS).